# SQL Query to calculate median and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following table.

```
DECLARE @TBL_RESULT Table
(   
    ID varchar(10),
    CreateDate DateTime,
    PEOPLE_CODE_ID varchar(10), 
    CONVERSION_DATE DateTime,
    CAMPUS varchar(20),
    DAYS_TOOK int   
);
```

This table has records from January 01,2013 to date of all the leads that were received and converted.

I initially needed to find the Median time it took to convert leads that arrived in last 10 weeks and group them by Campus  I was able to do that Using the SQL Query below

```
WITH    CTE_RESULT
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @TBL_RESULT
               WHERE    CreateDate > DATEADD(WEEK, -10, GETDATE())
             )
    SELECT  Campus ,
            AVG(DAYS_TOOK) AS MedianTime
    FROM    ( SELECT    CAMPUS ,
                        Days_Took ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Campus ORDER BY Days_Took ASC ) AS AgeRank ,
                        COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY CAMPUS ) AS CampusCount
              FROM      CTE_RESULT
            ) x
    WHERE   x.AgeRank IN ( x.CampusCount / 2 + 1, ( x.CampusCount + 1 ) / 2 )
    GROUP BY x.Campus
```

I now need to plot this trend on a graph i.e. find records the previous 10 weeks buckets and plot the median on a line chart - where each line is one campus. (Grouped by campus)

Is cursor my only option? where I will find the leads of first 10 week starting from Jan 01, do the above SQL query to get median, push it to a temp table and then find the next 10 weeks and so on.

Or is there anything better i can do?

Comment: No, you don't need a cursor for this. Can you clarify what you mean by "week"? Do you start on January 1st, and then 69 days later is the end of that 10 week period? Or are weeks defined by ISO week? Or defined by the date the script runs going backwards?

Comment: Initially when I wrote my query I just needed for last 10 weeks so I did a backward 10 week based on the date the script was run. So for example if script was run on 4/18 the Start date was 02/07.

Comment: @user1828125 . . . If you downvoted my answer, why?

Comment: I actually didn't - I pushed the up button, just double checked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without trying to optimise your query, if you need to produce the **same** result across multiple 10-WEEK periods, you can expand your current (10 week ago to today) ranges to as many ranges as required, threading a **PeriodEndDate** throughout the query as shown below.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3681)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @TBL_RESULT Table
(   
    ID varchar(10),
    CreateDate DateTime,
    PEOPLE_CODE_ID varchar(10), 
    CONVERSION_DATE DateTime,
    CAMPUS varchar(20),
    DAYS_TOOK int   
);

-- fill the table with some dummy data from 2013-01-01
INSERT @TBL_RESULT (CreateDate, Campus, Days_Took)
SELECT DATEADD(D, A.Number, '20130101'), 'Campus' + Right(B.Number, 10),
       ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) % 130) + 1
FROM master..spt_values A
JOIN master..spt_values B on B.type='P' and B.number < 50 -- 50 campuses
WHERE A.type='P'
  AND DATEADD(D, A.Number, '20130101') <= GetDate();

-- This first CTE is used to create the required number of 10-week periods
WITH N(NUMBER) AS (
  SELECT 0
  union all
  select number+1 from N
  where Number <= DATEDIFF(WEEK, '20130101', GETDATE())
),
-- and from below here it's your query with the PeriodEndDate threaded through
CTE_RESULT AS (
  SELECT   DATEADD(WEEK, -Number, GETDATE()) PeriodEndDate,
           T.*
  FROM     @TBL_RESULT T
  CROSS    JOIN     N
           -- you see the range built up dynamically here
  WHERE    CreateDate > DATEADD(WEEK, -Number-10, GETDATE())
    AND    CreateDate < DATEADD(WEEK, -Number, GETDATE()) +1
)
SELECT  PeriodEndDate, Campus ,
        AVG(DAYS_TOOK) AS MedianTime
FROM    (
         SELECT PeriodEndDate,   CAMPUS ,
         Days_Took ,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PeriodEndDate, Campus ORDER BY Days_Took ASC ) AS AgeRank ,
         COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY PeriodEndDate, CAMPUS ) AS CampusCount
         FROM      CTE_RESULT
        ) x
WHERE   x.AgeRank IN ( x.CampusCount / 2 + 1, ( x.CampusCount + 1 ) / 2 )
GROUP BY x.PeriodEndDate, x.Campus
ORDER BY x.PeriodEndDate, x.Campus;
```

Comment: Richard - Thank you for replying but I don't think this is giving me the median of 10 weeks combined. I expect one row for each campus for the whole 10 weeks period. Not one row per campus per week. 
The result I get from your query is actually giving me MEDIAN per campus per week.

Comment: The result is one row per CAMPUS per 10-WEEK period. Each data point is a MEDIAN across "one campus/10-week period", which is what you originally had. For example, where it says **`Campus "A" Period Ending "today" Median 100`** it means that for the 10-week period ending today for campus A the median is 100.

Comment: Richard - the solution you suggested is actually "Moving Median" where you slide by a week and then calculate the 10 week. I apologies my original question does not clarify this. But I actually have to do another report for moving median too, so you actually have answered my second question. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you solved the hard part of the problem.

To get what you want, you need to introduce a grouping variable.  In this case, I measure the number of weeks in the past and divide by 10 (SQL Server does integer division so this produces an integer).

You just then judiciously use this in the `partition by` and `group by` statements:

```
WITH CTE_RESULT AS (
       SELECT   t.*,
                DATEDIFF(week, CreateDate, GETDATE()) / 10 as groupnum
       FROM     @TBL_RESULT t
      )
SELECT Campus, groupnum, MIN(CreateDate), MAX(CreateDate),
       AVG(DAYS_TOOK) AS MedianTime
FROM (SELECT t.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY groupnum, Campus ORDER BY Days_Took ASC ) AS AgeRank ,
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY groupnum, CAMPUS) AS CampusCount
      FROM CTE_RESULT t
     ) x
WHERE x.AgeRank IN ( x.CampusCount / 2 + 1, ( x.CampusCount + 1 ) / 2 )
GROUP BY x.Campus, groupnum
```

I haven't tested this, so it might have a syntax error or two.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ seriously? are you going for the inb4 badge?

Comment: @swasheck Ծ_Ծ quite curious

Comment: @GordonLinoff "I haven't tested this, so it might have a syntax error or two." A caveat: I've not yet downvoted.

Comment: At least `groupnum` is missing from the derived table at the bottom. If a query is complex enough to look like magic to novices, then `have a syntax error or two` becomes increasingly unlikely to be fixable by the OP and the value of the answer steeply declines.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi . . . The answer was for the person who asked the question.  S/he seemed pretty sophisticated with SQL.  I thought I did  a pretty good job of explaining the approach to solving the problem.  The SQL was there as an example.

Comment: Gordon, your answer actually made some sense to me. I was thinking of introducing a variable of "10 weeks" bucket but I just didn't know where to plug that in.

I am sure the query you gave out won't run as is, but I will try to play with it. If you can think of something, please feel free to add

Comment: @user1828125 . . . For all the heat generated over this, the query *does* run.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Check the revision time on your post. You edited it after my comment.

Comment: I don't have an issue with you personally, but if the answer doesn't syntax check or solve the problem, then it isn't as useful to visitors to the page. StackOverflow is a very public site. Votes reflect the quality of the answer, not [only] how much it helps the OP. The OP gets a special vote for that called the "accept answer" checkbox. Now that you've fixed the syntax error, I can remove my downvote to reflect the *current* state of the answer.